# Expo Android Permissions set to nothing

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, expo

**What I would like**:
I want to be able to publish an APK file to the Play Store that has zero permissions, because my app does not require any.

**What I'm experiencing** 
When running the expo command `exp publish` I'm getting the following warning/issue

```
[exp] Making sure project is set up correctly...
[exp] Warning: Problem in app.json. See https://docs.expo.io/versions/v19.0.0/guides/configuration.html.
[exp]   - additional property "permission" exists in app.json when not allowed.
```

**Extra details**
Expo has released version 19 of their SDK which has the ability to set permissions for android. [see docs link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v19.0.0/guides/configuration.html#permissions)

There is no details on how to set *no permissions*, and the docs say the default will be applied when the permissions is not set in app.json without describing what those defaults are.

My config looks like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "test-publish",
    "description": "An empty new project",
    "slug": "test-publish",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "19.0.0",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "primaryColor": "#cccccc",
    "icon": "./assets/icons/app-icon.png",
    "loading": {
      "icon": "./assets/icons/loading-icon.png",
      "hideExponentText": false
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "assetExts": ["ttf", "mp4"]
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "permission": []
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're using `permission` (singular form) instead of plural.

Comment: No, if you look at the docs, you'll see "permissions" is the proper key to use.

Comment: yes, exactly. but you're using `permission` which is wrong

Comment: You're right in my example here I had the wrong value, however that was not the issue. The SDK had a bug in it which was causing the issue. They have since updated the SDK past V19.x which solves the issue. You can now publish the app with zero permissions (however it'll fail installing on the android platform, you need the very minimal permissions such as, can install on phone). Thanks for your help and pointing out the mistake in my example.

Comment: It was to use `permissions` instead of permission. I had a simple typo.